# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Гугл карты

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть такой код

```
  package com.perm.kate.api.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MapAct extends FragmentActivity {

  SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
  GoogleMap map;
  final String TAG = "myLogs";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    if (map == null) {
      finish();
      return;
    }
    init();
  }

  private void init() {

    }


  public void onClickTest(View view) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
  }
}
```

Я его вызываю на втором активити.
Он выдает такую ошибку

> 12-02 13:18:21.672: E/AndroidRuntime(15393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.perm.kate.api.sample/com.perm.kate.api.sample.MapAct}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference

Как это можно вылечить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ваш вариант кода написан для более поздних версий, тк Вы используете support library,то вам необходимо использовать getFragmentManager, как это описано в ответе ниже  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно инициализировать гугл-мап объект:

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Вместо

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

Comment: Странно,все равно тоже самое,и та же ошибка...

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.main); `
вот в чем была беда,весь смех.
`setContentView(R.layout.map);`
И заработало,правда серый экран и ошибка авторизации)